# postrgresql row by row comparison of values in two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, row

I have a postgres db where after a GROUPBY I have to evaluate entries approximated by this table:

[image]

I then try to find the MIN and MAX of each column and count the number of rows where there isn't a zero in either column 'A' or 'B'.  In this case I count one row because in row '4' there are non-zero values in both column 'A' and 'B'.  Getting MIN and MAX is straightforward but I can't figure out how to do the last step.

```
SELECT MIN(A) as "minA",
       MAX(A) as "maxA",
       MIN(B) as "minB",
       MAX(B) as "maxB",
       COUNT(????) as "num_full"
FROM bigDB
GROUPBY inlet
```

I thought maybe I could do a sum on each row and test if the result was equal to the value of 'A' or 'B' i.e. if A or B is zero then the sum is A or B.  But sum() works by column not row.  Is there a way to do sums by row or is there a better way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter`:

```
   COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE A <> 0 AND B <> 0) as num_full
```

There is no need to enclose column aliases in double quotes.